# Electron JS is not loading url with error code -21 and error description ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have created a desktop web application and URL for the application is https://localhost:8443/mayapp. I am loading application using electron JS framework. But here is one twist described as below:

I have created another html loading page accessed through url(file:///C:/Users/212807091/Desktop/laoding.html). What is happening is when electron app launches, It renders the load page. After some check condition passes then it loads actual application.

first page loaded:

**win.loadURL("file:///C:/Users/212807091/Desktop/laoding.html")**

When some checks condition passes then loads:

**win.loadURL("https://localhost:8443/mayapp")**

Electron FW is loading the first page without any error but throwing below error when it is trying to load actual application.

code to catch this error:

```
win.webContents.on("did-fail-load", function (event, errorCode, errorDescription) {
      log.error(`Unable to load login page with error: ${errorCode}-${errorDescription}`);
 });
```

**error code:** -21

**error description:** ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

**NOTE:**

- *This is an intermittent issue.*
- *File html page is on the host machine while web application is running in Kubernetes cluster.*

Could you guys please let me know what could be the cause of issue and how can we resolve it?

Comment: Why do you have one page as a file and the other as an application?

Comment: you can think of it as actual application is taking around 5 mins of time to come up on start up till then we have to show other page. That is why we have added static html page till actual application is not loaded.